# R Function call gives error "Incorrect number of parameters; there should be 4." How to format code so function is called correctly?

Tags: r

I have a very simple example I am trying to run which calls an R function from an external package.

I am using this [BTYD] (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BTYD/BTYD.pdf) package.

```
library(BTYD)  
library(dplyr) 


INPUT <- data.frame(R = 1:2, ALPHA = 3:4, S = 4:5, 
    BETA = 6:7, X = 8:9, T_X = 10:11, T_CAL = 12:13, D = 14:15 )

res <- transmute(INPUT, output = BTYD::pnbd.DERT(params = c(R,ALPHA,S,BETA),
                                                  x = X,
                                                  t.x = T_X,
                                                  T.cal = T_CAL, 
                                                  d = D))
```

When I run this in R Studio I get the following output

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>    Evaluation error: Error in pnbd.DERT: Incorrect number of parameters; there should be 4..

Not quite sure why this isn't working because when I replace all the variables in params, X, T_X, T_CAL, and D with random numbers it computes without any errors.

The particular function in the documentation requires that params be a vector

> Pareto/NBD parameters - a vector with r, alpha, s, and beta, in that order. r and
>   alpha are unobserved parameters for the NBD transaction process. s and beta
>   are unobserved parameters for the Pareto (exponential gamma) dropout process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some turmoil I found a solution. Using `rowwise()`function.

```
output <- INPUT %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute(output = BTYD::pnbd.DERT(params = c(R,ALPHA,S,BETA),
                                     x = X,
                                     t.x = T_X,
                                     T.cal = T_CAL,
                                     d = D))
```